# Dataframe replace() not replacing '-'s with with assigned value

Tags: python, pandas, replace, missing-data

I have a dataset that has been formatted to be entirely objects regardless of the content of the individual columns. I want to use this dataset for some basic linear regression modelling so need to get the dataset into a workable input. Most of the columns in the dataset are numeric and where they are missing a value for certain rows it uses a '-' to represent a missing value.

I need to replace the dashes with `np.NaN`'s and then format the columns to be floats. I have already removed any of the string columns like 'country' because fortunately, I do not need them at this stage.

I used:

```
for col in df:
  try:
    df[col] = df[col].replace(['-', ' '], np.NaN)
    df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
  except:
    # for row in df[col]:
      # if not isinstance(row, float):
      #   print(row)
    print('Could not convert ' + col)
```

and worked out that there was at least one white space hanging around in the data set so added it to the `replace()` method.

I had believed this to work, but come across difficulties with a subsequent step, so exported the data set after the replace step using `to_csv` and when I opened the file the only thing it had done was replace '-' with nothing. It was able to reformat the columns into floats though.

The step that is failing, and I don't know if it's because it's expecting a `np.NaN` is where I'm trying to fill in the remaining missing values with the mean of that column.

I'm using, and the dataframe has been renamed after dropping columns:

```
fill_mean = lambda col: col.df_response(col.mean())

for col in df_response:
  if df_response[col].isnull().sum() == 0:
    print(col + " no NaN's")
  else:
    try:
      df_response.apply(fill_mean, axis = 0)
      print(col + " worked as expected")
    except:
      print(col + ' did not replace NaN with mean')
```

This logic seems to work when there are no missing values and gives the column name and expected message. But where there are missing values, it does nothing and I get no error, just my message that it has failed.

I appreciate any insight.

Comment: Catching errors indiscriminately and then not doing anything with them is _bad practice_. The error can give you the insight you need into why your program _"did not replace NaN with mean"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your apply function is doing something but you are not storing it as a new dataframe, so it doesn't get returned back to you.

If you want to fill na rows with the mean you can do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Mick', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Mary'],
                  'Age': [17, 27, 37, np.nan]})

mean_age = df['Age'].mean()
df['Age'].fillna(mean_age)
```